# ROC of this LTI system given $x[n]$ and $y[n]$

Tags: z-transform

So I have a system with the following inputs and outputs:

\begin{align}
x[n]&=\left( \frac12 \right)^{n}u[n] + 2^{n}u[-n-1]\\
y[n]&=6\left( \frac12 \right)^{n}u[n] - 6\left( \frac34 \right)^{n}u[n]
\end{align}

The transfer function $H(z)$ can be found to be:

$$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{1-2z^{-1}}{1-\frac{3}{4}z^{-1}}$$

with a zero at $2$, and a pole at $\frac34$. Now how can we find the ROC of this system **given that one of the sequences ($x[n]$) has an anti-causal term?**

Comment: I see the point of your question now-- the input x[n] does not have a z-transform clearly due to no ROC overlap between causal and anti-causal parts, but given a transfer function that can have x[n] as an input (or any other input as the transfer function is independent of the input provided) can we also say the ROC does not exist?  (I am not confident that it can or can't, just elaborating on your question). Does the stated input which is not the system then imply that the ROC of the system must use the bilateral transform where no ROC would exist? Not sure, will watch for a better answer.

Comment: So no answers yet but really interested in hearing what the experts have to say. Without input from others that may know more, I would say that the Z-transform must be defined for the transfer function given (whether it is unilateral or bilateral) in order to give the ROC, as the transfer function is independent of the input.  However perhaps there is a convention that given the entire problem statement is defined with causal and non-causal inputs that the bilateral Z-Transform must be assumed. If no one answers please give us an update on what your professor says once you get the test back.

Comment: @DanBoschen: The input signal does have a Z-transform; its region of convergence is the annulus $\frac12<|z|<2$.

Comment: @MattL where I am getting confused is: Isn't $\sum_{-\infty}^0 u(-n)z^{-n} = \sum_0^{\infty}u(1/k)z^{-k}$ using the substitution that n = -1/k?  Also in general do we need to assume bilateral transform for ROC of the transfer function itself given the input was non-causal or does that need to be explicitly stated?

Comment: @MattL Good explanation below too. So it seems too in general we can always infer the cancellation that did occur from the resulting transfer function directly; meaning we did not need to be aware of the inputs and outputs that resulted in that transfer function; so by observation of the transfer function alone could have answered the question depending on what Z-transform we are dealing with. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @MattL OK I resolved my own confusions relating to the question two comments back regarding the substitution. Question in last comment still of interest however.

Comment: @DanBoschen: The substitution is simply $n\rightarrow -n$. I'm not sure if I understand your comment about the observation of the transfer function. Given only the transfer function, we can't generally know the corresponding ROC.

Comment: @MattL agree in that we need to define the index of the Z-transform ; if we are referring to a causal system or anti-causal. The question is if we can safely assume that for the question of finding the ROC for the system that we can infer the Z-transform indexing from the input given, or should that be explicitly stated when asking for an ROC regardless of what input was applied to determine the transfer function?  Also the substitution can't be n -> -n as that would no longer be a z-transform as z would be raised to a positive value of n, as opposed to the substitution I used, right?

Comment: @MattL but what I found was even with the substitution as I did it, it doesn't change the ROC as they way you stated- so I was good with all that.

Comment: @DanBoschen: The substitution doesn't change the expression, just as is the case with integration (variable substitution); it just makes the result more clearly visible. So it still is a valid Z-transform. The unilateral Z-transform only makes sense for causal signals. As soon as we have non-causal or anti-causal signals, we have to use the bilateral transform.

Comment: @MattL yes that part is clear regarding the substitution. So to be sure I get your last part let me state it in my words: because of the input given, it is clear to us that the problem statement asking about the transfer function assumes non-causal and causal signals and therefore when talking about the ROC of the transfer function we must assume the bilateral z-transform is implied.  There is no need in the question about the transfer function alone to specifically state which z-transform is used.  Concur?

Comment: @DanBoschen: that's right; the bilateral Z-transform naturally reduces to the unilateral transform if $x[n]=0$ for $n<0$, so I don't usually regard them as two "different Z-transforms".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the pole locations and the corresponding regions of convergence (ROCs) of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transforms of the input and output signals:

1. $X(z)$: poles at $z=\frac12$ and $z=2$ with ROC $\frac12<|z|<2$ (two-sided).
2. $Y(z)$: poles at $z=\frac12$ and $z=\frac34$ with ROC $|z|>\frac34$ (causal).

Now we know that the ROC of the multiplication of two $\mathcal{Z}$-transforms equals the intersection of the ROCs of the individual $\mathcal{Z}$-transforms, unless there is pole-zero cancellation, in which case the resulting ROC can be bigger than the intersection.

$H(z)$ has a zero at $z=2$ and a pole at $z=\frac34$. Since the zero cancels the pole of $X(z)$, the restriction $|z|<2$ for the ROC of $Y(z)$ is removed. The two theoretically possible ROCs of $H(z)$ are $|z|<\frac34$, corresponding to an anti-causal and unstable system, and $|z|>\frac34$, corresponding to a causal and stable system. In the first case, the ROC of $Y(z)$ would need to be $\frac12<|z|<\frac34$, which is not the case, and which would correspond to a two-sided unstable signal. $^1$ Consequently, the ROC of $H(z)$ must be $|z|>\frac34$, which means that the system described by $H(z)$ is causal and stable.

---

1. I use the term *unstable signal* for a signal that, if interpreted as the impulse response of an LTI system, would correspond to an unstable system (i.e., the ROC does not contain the unit circle).

Comment: On the second line in the last paragraph, don't you mean the restriction is removed for the ROC of $X(z)$ and not $Y(z)$?

Comment: @Valentin: No, I meant the restriction for the ROC of $Y(z)$, because the ROC of $X(z)$ is determined by $x[n]$ and can't be changed, whereas the ROC of $Y(z)$ is determined by the ROCs of $X(z)$ and $H(z)$, and is changed by pole-zero cancellations. The pole-zero cancellation changes the restriction for the ROC of $Y(z)$ initially imposed by the ROC of $X(z)$.